# How to send data from a C# ASP.NET Web Page to a java webservices

Tags: java, asp.net

I have created a C# ASP.NET web page(Front End) to collect information from user and I would like to know how to send the information to a java web services to process the information which is from the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post [How to invoke Java web service in ASP.net using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32313/How-to-invoke-Java-web-service-in-ASP-net-using-C) will give you some direction. Essentially, you need to:

1. Create a Java Web Service

   - Create a web application project
   - Add web service to the project
   - Add operations to the web service
   - Implement the web methods
   - Deploy and test the web service
2. Create ASP.net Web Site Using C#

   - Create ASP.net web site
   - Add a web reference
   - Write code to invoke web service
   - Test web service client application

The tutorial above by Bikash Shaw aims develop simple mathematical functions like addition, subtraction etc. using Java web services called `JSimpCalcWebService`:

```
package calc.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import calc.util.NumberFormater;

/**
* @author Bikash Shaw
*/
@WebService()
public class JSimpCalcWebService {

/**
  * Web service operation
  */
  @WebMethod(operationName = "addition")
  public String addition(@WebParam(name = "parameter1")
  double parameter1, @WebParam(name = "parameter2")
  double parameter2) {
 //TODO write your implementation code here:
      return NumberFormater.format((parameter1 + parameter2),0,6);
 }
```

}

Example C# code to invoke the web service:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using JSimpCalcWebServiceService;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    JSimpCalcWebServiceService.JSimpCalcWebServiceService proxy;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proxy = new JSimpCalcWebServiceService.JSimpCalcWebServiceService();
    }

   protected void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           lblResultAddition.Text = "Result: " +    proxy.addition(double.Parse(txtbtnAdditionParameter1.Text), 
                                double.Parse(txtbtnAdditionParameter2.Text));
       }
       catch (FormatException)
       {
           lblResultAddition.Text = "Result: Invalide Input";
       }
       UpdatePanelAddition.Update();
   }
 // Add more methods here...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java webservice should be talking in some protocol like SOAP/REST/Plain HTTP and you need to construct the request appropriately from your ASP.NET page upon submission of the form and send the request to the Java webservice.

Answer (score 0):

ENABLING WEBSERVICE  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
YOU CAN ACCESS DATA FROM WEBSERVICE USING JAVASCRIPT